# Common Custom fields in CRM Dynamics

Tags: customization, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to know if it is possible to create custom fields only once and use them through out multiple entities. For instance if I want to have a field called "Partner" and have it in Leads, Opportunities and Account. Can I just create the field only once and have it accessed in three different entities?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You'll need to create the field on each entity but you can share the data between them.

One way is a shared option set. This lets you manage one list of items and use it over and over on different entities. Another way you could go about it is to have a new entity for the data you're storing, and instead of creating a field you create a lookup to that record. This would be good if you had a list of countries that you wanted to reference all over CRM.